# How do you format localized strings to have single words of a sentence be a link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internationalization, string-formatting

I am working on a globalized web-app in ASP.NET MVC3. The project contains the I18N resources files and I normally access the resources inside my Razor views like...

```
@I18N.MyResourceString
```

I have a tricky situation which I have not been able to figure out a elegant solution to yet. I need to be able to localized the sentence "Click here to donate." where the word 'here' should be a link to our donation system.

Most links in the site are internal so to create link I simply write...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Some link text", "MyAction", "MyController")
```

This donation link is external. What I have so far (which is not working) is...

```
@String.Format(I18N.ClickHereToDonate, "<a href=\"http://paypal.com\">" + I18N.Here + "</a>")
```

where the `I18N.ClickHereToDonate` resource's text is `"Click {0} to donate."`.

What I see on the screen is...

```
Click <a href="http://paypal.com">here</a> to donate.
```

Furthermore, I would also like to add a 'title' attribute to the 'a' tag. It gets even uglier when I try that...

```
@String.Format(I18N.ClickHereToDonate, "<a href=\"http://paypal.com\" title=\"" + I18N.PayPal + "\">" + I18N.Here + "</a>")
```

There has to be a better way to form complex strings with embedded tags without concatenating things together in such a hackish manner. Not only does it not work (the intended markup got encoded) but it makes the HTML inside a string literal in my razor template which makes me loose any awesome IDE support/intergation/refactoring capabilities.

How can markup be injected into localized strings?

**UPDATE**
Adam Tuliper mentioned the `@Html.Raw` helper method in his answer so I added it to my already ugly markup...

```
@Html.Raw(String.Format(I18N.ClickHereToDonate, "<a href=\"http://paypal.com\" title=\"" + I18N.PayPal + "\">" + I18N.Here + "</a>"))
```

This *at least* got me a click-able link in the outputted markup.

> Click [here](http://paypal.com) to donate.

It is still a far-less-than-elegant solution though so I am still looking for better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try

```
<a href="http://paypal.com" title="@I18N.PayPal">@I18N.ClickHereToDonate</a>
```

Overall, you don't need the String format - you can just inject the Razor things inside normal html elements.

Edit: Incorporating the below:

```
@Html.Raw(String.Format(@I18N.ClickHereToDonate,String.Format("<a href='http://paypal.com' title='{0}'>{1}</a>", I18N.PayPal,I18N.Here)))
```

Comment: he does need string.format as the string above contains placeholders. {0}, etc

Comment: This is what I had to resort to for now but it is not the desired result. The business would like only the word "here" to be a link, not the entire sentence. Your answer is exactly what I already do for my menu item links which are all one word or only a few words.

Comment: I edited the above to use @Html.Raw - Adam used it below. Using two String.Formats should give you the desired result, without needing to change your resource strings or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are limited without built in support for this scenario (and there isn't in the helpers)
The cleaner way is to form your urls in a viewmodel and pass that view model to the view so you have minimal html. Your ViewModel contains
public class WhateverIndexViewModel
{
    public string Key {get;set;}
    public string URI {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;} 
}

Set the info in your controller, pass it to your view and use

```
<a href="@Html.Raw(Links["YourKey"].URI)">@Links["YourKey"].Title"</a>
```

As a basic idea.
Note if you dont want to use Html.Raw here then your URI in the class would be of type MvcString not String this way @Links["YourKey"].URI won't be html encoded.

Comment: The `Html.Raw` did help me get the markup not encoded like I described in my questions. But I don't understand how what you are describing will help me embed that link into a localized string...